What is causing this wall to be so wet?
I am working on a house with a small bathroom on a west-facing wall with a window and sandwiched between a bedroom to the south and a bathroom to the north:

The outside west-facing wall is made of brick and looks like this (and was recently re-rendered after this photo was taken in 2021):

The south wall is also brick and the north wall is lath and plaster.
The bathroom was fine from 2017-2019 with the walls and paintwork in good condition:

However, at some point in 2020 the walls got very damp and discoloured, paint flaked off and the effloresced.
South wall:

Details either side of toilet:

Ceiling:

This is the current state of the whole bathroom:

Despite the very poor condition of the walls, this does not seem to have got worse in the last 4 years. However, the wall is still very damp in places.
The west and south walls and the ceiling are still very wet when measured with a damp-meter:
Here's an animation showing a "dampmap" of the south wall. The darker the blue the damper the brick under the paint:

The dampest parts are in the top left corner and forming a rough diagonal line going up and to the right.
Here's a "dampmap" of the same projection looking at the south wall also showing the ceiling above and the right side of the west-wall on the left.
Wall:

Dampmap:

I don't know where the water has been coming from.
The other side of the south wall (inside the bedroom) shows no sign of water ingress.
The loft space above is bone dry and the continuation of the brick wall into the loft is also very dry. The lead flashing above seems to be in good condition too.
Could this all have started coming in very quickly in 2020 and caused all this damage before the exterior wall was re-rendered in 2021? The worst parts of both walls and ceiling are still very wet.
The external wall looks like this:

There is also a small horizontal crack above the lintel of the window. Could water be getting in here:

The whole room needs replastering but I'm reluctant to do anything unless I can be sure no more water is getting in.

Where on the planet is this home and has the roof been checked for leaks?

If there is not a floor above it, then there are no water pipes in the ceiling.  A roof leak is the prime suspect.

@RMDman - as per the question "The loft space above is bone dry and the continuation of the brick wall into the loft is also very dry". The house is in northern Europe near the coast.

@SteveWellens even though the pattern of wetness is worst around the window and it's not continuous going down the wall and that the loft is dry above?

We don't know how the loft is built, or the roof. There could be a roof leak and the water runs down the wall until it collects in the bathroom wall .  Post a picture of the outside so we can see the entire side of the house.

What's the external humidity?  If it's near the coast, I'm guessing it ranges between 50% and 100% with 70% typical.  You might try measuring the internal humidity.  Do people use the fan in the adjacent bathroom when they use the bathtub?  It's an internal wall, but you might check if it gets extra cold for some reason.

how is this room ventilated?

A leak can easily travel down through an exterior wall and then start accumulating broadly when it hits the top plate of a wall. Have you brought in someone with an infrared camera to look around here?

there is no ventilation as it is so small. the other bathroom has a powerful extractor running based on humidity and the bedroom has a powerful dehumidifier

@RMDman I've been to the property today and taken a photo of the external wall. The loft is bone dry as per the question and is covered in tiles.

I was hoping for a broader picture of the entire side of the house.  My instincts tell me this is a result of water infiltration from above, namely the roof  or an adjacent vent or other port.

@RMDman I've updated with the best photo I can manage from a wide angle lens. I think you might be right but do you mind talking through some of your reasoning how you are coming to that conclusion? Thanks

I fully believe this is coming from a roof or roof to sidewall leak.

I would examine the roof to sidewall area ( yellow) paying great attention to the area circled in blue.
There can be minor defects in the sealing that will allow water to seep into the structure and gather over time in the bathroom wall and ceiling.

Thank you. I will do exactly that. However, how does that explain the pattern of dampness I have measured on the wall with the diagonal pattern?

The pattern cannot be explained without knowing of all the components inside and above the wall.  A number of things can affect the movement of water.  This knowledge is moot to correcting the problem.
